# Redshift - How to use column in one table as pattern in SIMILAR TO

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a problem where I have two tables. One table constains urls and their information and another groups of urls that should be grouped by a pattern.

```py
Urls table:
------------------------------------------------
| url                                  | files |
| https://myurl1/test/one/es/main.html | 530   |
| https://myurl1/test/one/en/main.html | 530   |
| https://myurl1/test/one/ar/main.html | 530   |
------------------------------------------------

Urls patterns table:
---------------------------------------------
| group  | url_pattern                      |
| group1 | https://myurl1/test/one/(es|en)/%|
| group2 | https://myurl1/test/one/(ar)/%   |
---------------------------------------------
```

I have tried something like this bearing in mind that url_patterns will only have one row per group.

```sql
SELECT * FROM urls_table
WHERE url SIMILAR TO (SELECT MAX (url_pattern) FROM url_patterns WHERE group='group1')
LIMIT 10
```

The main problem here is that it seems that applying SIMILAR TO with a column argument is not working.

[image]

Could anyone give me some advices?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution looks pretty good from here, are you having problems?  Your Select MAX(...) indicates there might be several patterns for the same group.  To select where URL matches any pattern try `Select Distinct URL,files from urls_table, url_pattern where url Similar To url_pattern`

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: Hello, the first problem is that it seems that is not possible to apply similar to to a subquery. That's why I applied MAX to try to get only and String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into the requirement that regexp patterns are compiled and that SIMILAR TO is a layer on regexp.  So what you are trying to do won't work.  I believe there are a number of other ways to do this.

I) Change to LIKE pattern matching: LIKE patterns aren't precompiled so can use dynamic patterns.  The downside is that they are more limited but I think you can still do what you want.  Just change your patterns to be set of pattern columns (if the number of patterns is limited) and test for all the patterns.  Unneeded patterns can just be a value that can never match.  Definitely a brute force hack.

II) Change to LIKE pattern matching w/ SQL to provide OR behavior:  have multiple LIKE patterns in the url_pattern column separated by '|' (for example).  Then use split_part to match each sub-pattern - a bit complex and possible slow but works.  Like this:

```
SELECT url
FROM urls_table
LEFT JOIN (SELECT split_part(pattern, '|', part_no::int) as pattern
              FROM url_patterns
              CROSS JOIN (SELECT row_number() over () as part_no FROM urls_table)
              WHERE "group" = 'group1'
             )
ON url LIKE pattern 
WHERE p.pattern IS NOT NULL;
```

You will also need to change your pattern strings to use the simpler LIKE format and use '|' for multiple possibilities - Ex: Group1 pattern becomes 'https://myurl1/test/one/es/%|https://myurl1/test/one/en/%'

III) Use some front-end query modification to find the pattern for the group and apply it to query BEFORE it is sent to the compiler.  This could be an external tool or a stored procedure on Redshift.  Get the pattern in one query and use it to issue the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `exists`?

```
SELECT u.*
FROM urls_table u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM url_patterns p
              WHERE u.url SIMILAR TO p.url_pattern AND
                    p.group = 'group1'
             )
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Does this not break Redshift's correlated sub-query restriction?